# Surface integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions, vector-analysis, parametric

**Problem statement**
$$
\mbox{Calculate the surface integral}\quad
\int_{Y}\ y\,\sqrt{z\,}\,\sqrt{4x^{2} + 4y^{2} + 1\,}\,\,{\rm d}S
$$
where $Y$ is the surface
$\left\{\left(x,y,z\right)\ \ni\ z=x^2+y^2\,,\ y \geq 0\,,\  y \geq -x\,,\
1 \leq x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 4\right\}$.

**Progress**

I am trying to visualize the surface step by step. So $z=x^2+y^2$ is an infinite paraboloid, $y\geq 0$ gives us only half of this paraboloid(one side of the y-axis), $y\geq -x$ does not restrict anything(?) and $1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 4$ is either: The area between the two circles of radius 1 and 2 OR(since $z=x^2+y^2$) equivalent to $1\leq z\leq 4$(How large are the circles then...?)

Some guidance would be helpful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your surface:

[image]

I generated it with the following Mathematica code.  If you can make sense of the code, particularly the `ParametricPlot3D` command, then you can probably see how the $y=-x$  affects the surface and what your bounds of integration will be after you set up the surface integral as an iterated integral.

```
bounds = ContourPlot3D[{y == 0, y == -x, z == 1, z == 4},
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 5},
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.3],
 Mesh -> None];
surface = ParametricPlot3D[{r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t], r^2}, {t, 0, 3 Pi/4}, 
  {r, 1, 2}, BoundaryStyle -> Thick];
Show[{bounds, surface}]
```

After a bit of algebra, you should find yourself getting to

$$\int _1^4\int _0^{3\pi/4}r^3 \left(1+4
   r^2\right) \sin (t)\,dt\,dr = \frac{11175}{8} \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right).$$

Comment: Yes, I carried out the integration and arrived at the same answer(it is wrong though). However, the trick here(I believe) is to be able to visualize this surface(or at least to set up the bounds via parametrization). Not really obvious.

Comment: And thank you Mark, I appreciate it.

Comment: Never mind, it should be 183 instead of 11175, that's all.

Comment: The $r$ integral is over $\left(1,2\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

A hint:

Your surface can be parametrized by introducing polar coordinates in the $(x,y)$-plane as follows:

$$(r,\phi)\ \mapsto\  (r\cos\phi,\  r\sin\phi,\  r^2)\ .$$

Now you have to do three things: First find the exact parameter domain in the $(r,\phi)$-plane,  then express the integrand and $dS$ in terms of $r$ and $\phi$, and finally integrate.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{Y}\ y\root{z}\root{4x^{2} + 4y^{2} + 1}\,\dd{\rm S}}$

$\ds{Y \equiv\braces{\pars{x,y,z}\ \ni\ z=x^2+y^2\,,\ y \geq 0\,,\  y \geq -x\,,\
1 \leq x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 4}}$

> The surface $\ds{Y}$ is parametrized by $\ds{x}$ and $\ds{y}$ as
>   $\ds{\vec{r} = x\,\hat{x} + y\,\hat{y} + \pars{x^{2} + y^{2}}\,\hat{z}}$ such that
>   \begin{align}
> \dd{\rm S} &=\verts{\partiald{\vec{r}}{x}\times\partiald{\vec{r}}{y}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
> =\verts{\pars{\hat{x} + 2x\,\hat{z}}\times\pars{\hat{y} + 2y\,\hat{z}}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
> =\verts{\hat{z} - 2y\,\hat{y} + 2x\,\hat{x}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
> \\[3mm]&=\root{4x^{2} + 4y^{2} + 1}\,\dd x\,\dd y
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large\int_{Y}\ y\root{z}\root{4x^{2} + 4y^{2} + 1}\,\dd{\rm S}}
=\int_{Y}\ y\root{x^{2} + y^{2}}\pars{4x^{2} + 4y^{2} + 1}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[3mm]&=\left.\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd\rho\,\rho
\bracks{\rho\sin\pars{\theta}\rho\pars{4\rho^{2} + 1}}
\vphantom{\Huge A^A}\right\vert
_{\sin\pars{\theta}\ \geq\ 0 \atop {\vphantom{\Huge A}\sin\pars{\theta}\ \geq\ -\cos\pars{\theta} \atop {\vphantom{\Huge A}1\ \leq\ \rho\ \leq 2}}}
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{3\pi/4}\dd\theta\int_{1}^{2}\dd\rho\,\rho^{3}
\sin\pars{\theta}\pars{4\rho^{2} + 1}
=\pars{1 + {\root{2} \over 2}}\int_{1}^{2}\pars{4\rho^{5} + \rho^{3}}\,\dd\rho
\\[3mm]&=\pars{1 + {\root{2} \over 2}}\,{183 \over 4}
=\color{#00f}{\large\pars{2 + \root{2}}{183 \over 8}} \approx 78.1001
\end{align}

Comment: @EricAm You're welcomE. I enjoy that.